# MathOverflow at the Joint Mathematics Meetings, Baltimore, January 2014

Tags: discussion

The [2014 Joint Mathematics Meetings](http://jointmathematicsmeetings.org/jmm) will be held January 15-18, 2014 in Baltimore, with <strike>hundreds</strike> **thousands** of mathematicians attending.  It happens that I plan to attend, and since I'd enjoy going to talks by many of the various MathOverflow personalities I've come to know in recent years, I'd like to know who from MO will be speaking there.

**Question.** Which MathOverflow people will be speaking at the JMM?

Please answer with a link to the entry in the program.

Also, will there be any MathOverflow gatherings there? If nothing is yet planned, shall we organize something?

Comment: "...hundreds of mathematicians attending." It's going to be a small meeting then --- the 2013 meeting drew over 6000 registrants.

Comment: Thanks, Gerry, I'm glad to hear that I should say "thousands."  Indeed, in my original post I had actually written "thousands", but lost confidence and so changed it to "hundreds". But I expect that the meeting will be bigger than ever! I've edited it back in.

Comment: Here's the  complete list of presenters at the JMM: http://jointmathematicsmeetings.org/meetings/national/jmm2014/2160_presenters.html

Comment: I wish I wish I wish I could come to that...

Answer (score 15):

I will be giving the opening talk in the MAA Invited Paper Session "Six Crash Courses on Mapping Class Groups", which consists of a sequence of 45 minute introductory talks on various aspects of the mapping class group (thus it's really more of a short course than a traditional invited paper session, though each lecture in the course will be given by a different person).  The page for my talk is [here](http://jointmathematicsmeetings.org/amsmtgs/2160_abstracts/1096-ag-879.pdf).

Answer (score 12):

My talk for the ASL will be Saturday, January 18, 2:00 - 2:50, Room 319, BCC.

- [Embeddability amongst the countable models of set theory](http://jointmathematicsmeetings.org/meetings/national/jmm2014/2160_program_saturday.html#2160%3aHAMKINS)

Answer (score 12):

I wonder if it make sense, at some future *[Joint Mathematics Meetings](http://jointmathematicsmeetings.org/jmm)* (JMM), 
to have a MathOverflow **booth** among the "Exhibitors"?
Not all booths are publishers. For example, the *Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences* has a booth at JMM, as does the *Museum of Mathematics*.
I know nothing of the financial aspects of this, but it certainly would raise MO's visibility in the U.S.
Of course, this assumes that raising MO's visibility is desirable.

One could ask the same question for equivalent broad math conferences worldwide.

Comment: ...as does the Electronic Frontier Foundation (http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/01/the_electronic_frontier_founda.html) - booths can be there for all sorts of reasons.  I like the idea of a MO booth, but I'm not sure what it would do.  Maybe people could leave their questions, the MO-er at the booth would ask it on MO, then the person could come back the next day to see if they'd got an answer.  Sort of like the Mechanical Turk.

Comment: There was a bulletin board at the meeting in 2010 (or was it 2011?) where people could post questions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson looking at the old thread dicussing this it seems both 2010 and 2011 http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/112 // See also the User 2010 Joint Meetings http://mathoverflow.net/users/3149/2010-joint-meetings

Comment: That's possible. We're about to become an official 501(c)(3) nonprofit, which will allow us to raise money for such things on our own. Could you make this a feature request for the next JMM?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: I am afraid I do not understand what constitutes "a feature request for the next JMM"?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: Post a feature-request question on meta. We can then hash out details of organizing such a thing.

Answer (score 7):

Bill Johnson will talk on Saturday at 9 am about [Embeddings of $\ell_p(\aleph)$ spaces into $L_p$ spaces](http://jointmathematicsmeetings.org/amsmtgs/2160_abstracts/1096-46-1381.pdf).

Comment: Quid, will you be speaking? We'd be happy to link to your talk.

Comment: No. That'd been a fun way to identify myself though :-) Maybe another year.

Comment: Well, we'll all look forward to that!

Answer (score 4):

Mark Sapir will speak on [Uniform embedding of groups into Banach spaces](http://jointmathematicsmeetings.org/meetings/national/jmm2014/2160_program_saturday.html#2160%3aSS16B) on Saturday at 3 pm.

Answer (score 3):

Carl Mummert will speak on [The modal logic of reverse mathematics](http://jointmathematicsmeetings.org/meetings/national/jmm2014/2160_program_friday.html#2160%3aASLCP1)  on Friday at 3pm.