# Booth at Joint Mathematics Meeting?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, site-promotion

This is identical to my misplaced "answer" [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/1412/6094), written while attending JMM. I am reposting a fresh question at François G. Dorais's request.

---

I wonder if it make sense, at some future Joint Mathematics Meetings (JMM), to have a MathOverflow booth among the "Exhibitors"? Not all booths are publishers. For example, the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences has a booth at JMM , as does the Museum of Mathematics. I know nothing of the financial aspects of this, but it certainly would raise MO's visibility in the U.S. Of course, this assumes that raising MO's visibility is desirable.

One could ask the same question for equivalent broad math conferences worldwide.

Comment: I would say that raising the visibility might not always be desirable. But when the people that get this visibility are those attending JMM, it would seem ideal, as those are precisely the people we need to know about MO and what they might use it for.

Comment: According to http://www.eventsinamerica.com/events/ams-american-mathematical-society-2015-joint-mathematics-meeting/ev490604141a937/ the cost of a booth in 2015 range from 424 to 1833 dollars; the two smaller categories 424 and 605 are only available under certain restrictions along the lines 'small' and 'new' but presumably MO would qualify (or there might be even something still better for something like MO, that information rather being geared towards commercial exhibitors).

Comment: @quid: Those prices are correct. Additional costs include staffing: we would have to pay travel, lodging and expenses for enough staff to support the booth for the duration of the exhibit. Altogether, it's a significant amount but once MO is an official non-profit organization, we will be able to raise money through grants and donations.

Comment: Perhaps something else to consider at JMM meetings is to have a mathoverflow reception?  (Again, the funding question is an issue).

Comment: Perhaps at some point in the future the AMS (Amer Math Society) might decide that MathOverflow has become an important resource for the mathematics community, and fund some type of presence at major meetings. Until then, ...